# Optimal way to initialize heavy services only once in FastAPI

Tags: python, initialization, singleton, global, fastapi

The FastAPI application I started  working on, uses several services, which I want to initialize only once, when the application starts and then use the methods of this object in different places.
It can be a cloud service or any other heavy class.

Possible ways is to do it with `Lazy loading` and with `Singlenton pattern`, but I am looking for better approach for FastAPI.

Another possible way, is to use `Depends` class and to cache it, but its usage makes sense only with route methods, not with other regular methods which are called from route methods.
Example:

```
async def common_parameters(q: Optional[str] = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return {"q": q, "skip": skip, "limit": limit}  
    

async def non_route_function(commons: dict = Depends(common_parameters)):
    print(commons)         # returns `Depends(common_parameters)` 
    

@router.get('/test')
async def test_endpoint(commons: dict = Depends(common_parameters)):
    print(commons)         # returns correct dict
    await non_route_function()
    return {'success': True}
```

There can be also used `@app.on_event("startup")` event to initialize heavy class there, but have no idea how to make this initialized object accessible from every place, without using `singleton`.

Another ugly way is also  to  save initialized objects into @app( and then get this app from requests, but then you have to pass `request` into each non-route function.

All of the ways I have described are either ugly, uncovenient, non-pythonic or worse practice, we also don't have here thread locals and proxy objects like in flask, so what is the best approach for such kind of problem I have  described above?

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you can't do something like `result_from_non_route_function = Depends(non_route_function)` in your route signature when you need access to the result? Additionally, you can wrap it in an lru_cache decorator (as shown with the config dependency in the FastAPI reference, iirc).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MatsLindh, but what if route method calls second, and second method calls third,  where we need that dependency? I have to pass `Depends` stuff on each function, it's super inconvenient for readability and maintenance. 
Also, it is not caching mechanism I am worrying about, it's about proper architectural solution on application side.

Comment: Well, then it depends on where you need the reference to your service. Some sort of dependency should be injected into your controller since you need to decide what action the controller should take. In that case you can inject the dependent service (if that dependency depends on something else) in the function you use to create the dependency - so that the service layer wraps the operations you want to perform on your data and exposes those relevant operations to your controller.

Comment: Thanks again @MatsLindh, understand what you mean, but Dependenices generally as the  `Depends` class in Fastapi exists for completely different reasons, not to initialize heavy services, but to make your modules more abstrat dependents.   
I just mentioned what  limits FastAPI Depends has, to emphasize that it doesn't fixes my problem.  And my problem is not to use `Depends` with some weird ways, but to initialize heavy services conveniently.

Comment: I see; thanks for expanding. This is just my experience: In those cases we've usually initialized the heavy service in the same location as were we set up the `app` object - they're both relevant to the startup of the application. We then wrap it in a service class as necessary to hide away the actual import and implementation if we need to change it later, but so far this has worked fine for us. We then use this service class together with a `Depends` hierarchy that populates the relevant services and arguments as needed by the routes (the heavy class is initialized on application startup).

Comment: The heavy initialization itself would depend on the requirements of the module itself, but is usually done with a helper function in the module (of the heavy service) or as a class or static method on a helper class. I prefer to avoid Singletons as they're not testing friendly and imposes arbitrary limitations that might turn up as issues later (if we suddenly need to talk to two different instances of the same cloud service, for example).

Comment: Agree! @MatsLindh can you  please show me an simple example of what you described?  I mean the heavy class initialization and then service of this class. I just want to see how you accessing from service class on the initialized object which is in the  same file as app.  You can show me the code in `answer`, instead of `comment.

Comment: Sorry about the delay; I had to find some time to carve out a more complete example to show how I'd solve it. Seems to work fine with my examples and mirrors how I've been solving similar issues for certain backend services.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's usually a good idea to initialize the heavy objects before launching the FastAPI application. That way you're done with initialization when the application starts listening for connections (and is made available by the load balancer).

You can set up these dependencies and do any initialization in the same location as you set up your app and main routers, since they're a part of the application as well. I usually expose the heavy object through a light weight service that exposes useful endpoints to the controllers themselves, and the service object is then injected through `Depends`.

Exactly how you want to perform the initialization will depend on what other requirements you have in the application - for example if you're planning to re-use the infrastructure in cli tools or use them in cron as well.

This is the way I've been doing it in a few projects, and so far it has worked out fine and kept code changes located in their own vicinities.

Simulated heavy class in `heavylifting/heavy.py` with `from .heavy import HeavyLifter` in `__init__.py`:

```py
import time

class HeavyLifter:
    def __init__(self, initial):
        self.initial = initial
        time.sleep(self.initial)
    
    def do_stuff(self):
        return 'we did stuff'
```

A skeleton project created in a module named `foo` (`heavylifting` lives under `foo/heavylifting` for now to make sense of the imports below):

**foo/app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from .heavylifting import HeavyLifter

heavy = HeavyLifter(initial=3)

from .views import api_router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(api_router)
```

**foo/services.py**

The service layer in the application; the services are the operations and services that the application exposes to controllers, handling business logic and other co-related activities. If a service needs access to heavy, it adds a `Depends` requirement on that service.

```py
class HeavyService:
    def __init__(self, heavy):
        self.heavy = heavy
        
    def operation_that_requires_heavy(self):
        return self.heavy.do_stuff()
        
class OtherService:
    def __init__(self, heavy_service: HeavyService):
        self.heavy_service = heavy_service
        
    def other_operation(self):
        return self.heavy_service.operation_that_requires_heavy()
```

**foo/app_services.py**

This exposes the services defined to the application as dependency lightweight injections. Since the services only attach their dependencies and gets returned, they're quickly created for a request and then discarded afterwards.

```py
from .app import heavy
from .services import HeavyService, OtherService
from fastapi import Depends

async def get_heavy_service():
    return HeavyService(heavy=heavy)
    
async def get_other_service_that_uses_heavy(heavy_service: HeavyService = Depends(get_heavy_service)):
    return OtherService(heavy_service=heavy_service)
```

**foo/views.py**

Example of an exposed endpoint to make FastAPI actually serve something and test the whole service + heavy chain:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from .services import OtherService
from .app_services import get_other_service_that_uses_heavy

api_router = APIRouter()

@api_router.get('/')
async def index(other_service: OtherService = Depends(get_other_service_that_uses_heavy)):
    return {'hello world': other_service.other_operation()}
```

**main.py**

The application entrypoint. Could live in `app.py` as well.

```py
from fooweb.app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run('fooweb.app:app', host='0.0.0.0', port=7272, reload=True)
```

This way the heavy client gets initialized on startup, and uvicorn starts serving requests when everything is live. Depending on how the heavy client is implemented it might need to pool and recreate sockets if they can get disconnected for inactivity (as most database libraries offer).

I'm not sure if the example is easy enough to follow, or that if it serves what you need, but hopefully it'll at least get you a bit further.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh so much for such a great example and comprehensive answer! 
it is more clear than to add extra params into `@app` and thne to try to fetch it in another place. 
You really helped me!

Comment: Declaring the `HeavyLifter` object as a module-level global is a bit icky. It will make it impossible to import the `app` module without doing all that heavyweight work. FastAPI [startup and shutdown events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/) are a little better, especially since they give you an opportunity to clean up gracefully when the application stops. (Not that they don't have [their own ickiness.](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/617))

Comment: An alternative to startup and shutdown events is to use an async context manager that gets passed as the [lifespan](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan) parameter to `FastAPI()` if your python version is recent enough. Note that that is the same page as the "startup and shutdown events" page in Maxpm's comment.

Comment: Also note that the FastAPI documentation is not versioned, and that `lifespan` parameter was only added two weeks ago.

Comment: What if the heavy service requires cleanup?

Comment: @foxtrotuniform6969 Then it depends on when that cleanup should run - whether it's at the end of each request, or when the server terminates